# Get metadata for cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

The document body of a cross origin website within an iframe is essentially a black box. Unless message posting is explicitly implemented you are essentially out of luck getting your hands on any data.

But surely there is some sort of metadata about the iframe itself. Is it possible to find out how much memory the iframe uses? Is it using processing power? What information about the iframe is accessible to a script?

Comment: Is that kind of information available about the main window/document? If it's any help, the iframe is an HTMLIFrameElement, which is derived from HTMLElement, so you can get any of the properties of those.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement